# What numerical methods with variable step size are effective for computing double/triple integrals?

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

The professor asked me to write a small computer program that takes double integrals of rapidly varying functions. He did not mention which functions should be integrated but he said that I must use a numerical method with variable step size.

I hope someone can recommend me a method that will do the job. It would be nice to have a link where this method is adequately described.